# Could not see Windows Experience Subscores

Tags: windows-7, windows-experience-index

I could see my Windows Experience Score.  But when I click the Rating.  Windows 7 doesn't display the subscores.

Any idea what's wrong ?

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 1):

The following conditions might prevent Windows from updating the Windows Experience Index:

•**Running on battery power**.‌ Windows automatically tries to conserve power when running on a battery alone. So if your computer is running on battery power, a performance assessment won't reflect its true capabilities. Plug your computer in, and then re-run the assessment.

•**Not enough free disk space.** The Windows Experience Index assessment tool creates a test file on your hard disk. If there's not enough free disk space to create the test file, the assessment can't be completed. You can use the Disk Cleanup tool to free up disk space. For more information, see Delete files using Disk Cleanup.

•**The assessment is already running.** If the Windows Experience Index assessment tool is already running, your scores can't be updated.

•**The display driver is older**. If your computer is using an older version of the display driver, your scores might not be updated. For more information, see Update drivers: recommended links

•**No multimedia support**. If your computer doesn't have multimedia support, your scores can't be updated.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/What-is-the-Windows-Experience-Index)